# A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException' occurred in Microsoft.Build.dll

Tags: c#, executable, vcxproj

I am trying to extract various properties from vcxproj projects. These properties include the TargetName and TargetExtension. As I am looping through all of the project types with this extension I am creating a temporary project and extracting qualities from this project like so:

```
 file = "PATH TO SOME VCXPROJ FILE"
 var project = new Project(file); <-- BREAKS HERE
 outputName = project.GetPropertyValue("TargetName");
 outputExtension = project.GetPropertyValue("TargetExt");
```

Some of the projects pass the point where it breaks (outlined above) and some do not and output the error

> A first chance exception of type Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException' occurred in Microsoft.Build.dll

I did some digging and found that for some projects the line

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
```

executes just fine and some do not. In other words `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` can be located sometimes and other times it can not. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.